# passing data between fragments android

Tags: java, android

i have a recycle view that have an onclick function that uses an interface to pass the position of the clicked item to the fragment that the recycle view that its populated on
now i was trying to pass that position to another fragment but it gets an null pointer reference error because the data wasnt sent

the following code is from the adapter

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    recycleclick.onclic(holder.getAdapterPosition());

}
```

the following code from the first fragment (i also tried to put the bundle code inside the oncreate function but it got the same result )

```
    @Override
public void onclic(int position) {
    //list.get(position);
    //Log.d(TAG, "onclic: done");
 System.out.println(position);
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "aight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    thepostion=position;
    GalleryFragment fragment = new GalleryFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("themed",thepostion);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);


}
```

the following code is from the second fragment (the code is inside the oncreate function)

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    int x = bundle.getInt("themed");
    System.out.println("gallery" + x);
```

Comment: i don't see where you're starting `GalleryFragment`, where's that code ? are you sure you're starting the fragment that you've set the arguments on ?

Comment: yeah i just didnt get the full gallery fragment code .
the gallery fragment gets started and i get the error when the getint function gets invoked